# How do I make floating ip pools available in OpenStack?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

On the controller:

```
> nova-manage floating list
None    192.168.1.1     None    public  eth0
None    192.168.1.2     None    public  eth0
None    192.168.1.3     None    public  eth0
...

> nova floating-ip-bulk-list   (with admin credentials)
+------------+---------------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| project_id | address       | instance_uuid | pool   | interface |
+------------+---------------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| -          | 192.168.1.1   | -             | public | eth0      |
| -          | 192.168.1.2   | -             | public | eth0      |
| -          | 192.168.1.3   | -             | public | eth0      |
| -          | 192.168.1.4   | -             | public | eth0      |
...


(with admin or other user credentials on "admin" tenant or another project tenant)
> nova floating-ip-list

> nova floating-ip-pool-list
```

I can't figure out how to make the IPs in the public pool as shown by nova-manage show up to the normal nova (or web) client so I can assign them to an instance.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. What is the user/tenant you are using in the first and second scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the folks who setup the OpenStack instance are using neutron to manage networking so "neutron floatingip-create" seems to have worked.